# How to obtain the mean for a normal distribution given its quartiles?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, mean, descriptive-statistics, quantiles

Assuming we have a normal distribution for which the mean and standard deviation are unknown, how are first and third quartiles related to the mean?

Comment: Right in the middel og the 1. and 3. quartile is the median (because of symmetry). Further for the normal you have that the mean is placed exactly the same place as the median

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With two quartiles (or any other two percentiles) of a normal distribution you can always compute mean and standard deviation. We start with the formulas to compute quartiles from distribution parameters:

$$Q_1=\mu+CDF^{-1}(0.25)·\sigma=\mu-0.67449·\sigma$$
$$Q_3=\mu+CDF^{-1}(0.75)·\sigma=\mu+0.67449·\sigma$$

Where $CDF^{-1}$ stands for inverse of cumulative distribution function of standard normal distribution, $\mu$ stands for mean and $\sigma$ stands for standard deviation.

Solving the equations for $\mu$ and $\sigma$:

$$\mu=\frac{Q_1+Q_3}{2}$$
$$\sigma=\frac{Q_3-Q_1}{CDF^{-1}(0.75)-CDF^{-1}(0.25)}=\frac{Q_3-Q_1}{2·CDF^{-1}(0.75)}=\frac{Q_3-Q_1}{1.34898}$$